# Passing parameter other activity

Tags: android, android-activity, parameters, android-intent

Top of my code

```
    package com.br.openeed.engtoolspro;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TubulaoDados extends Activity {

    // WIDGETS
    Spinner spTsolo;
    Button btCalcular;
    EditText etCarga, etMenorbase;
    TextView tvMenorbase, tvCm;

    // VARIABLES
    double valorCarga, valorTsolo, valorMenorbase, cargaKgf,
            verificacaoOblongada, verificacaoOblongada2, maiorBase, menorBase,
            areaFuste, diametroFuste, valorAlturabase, volumeBase;
```

I have the following method that is called after the calculations of the User:

```
// Writes the results to other activity

    public void chamaResultados() {
        Intent ITubulaoDados = new Intent(TubulaoDados.this,
                TubulaoResultados.class);
        ITubulaoDados.putExtra("resultadoDiametrofuste", diametroFuste);
        startActivity(ITubulaoDados);
    }
```

In another activity'm have:

```
    package com.br.openeed.engtoolspro;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TubulaoResultados extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.tubulaoresultados);

        final TextView tvResultadofuste;
        Intent ITubulaoDados = getIntent();
        final String resultadoFuste;

        if (ITubulaoDados != null) {
            tvResultadofuste.setText(Double.parseDouble(diametroFuste));
            Log.i("TubulaoResultados","resultadoDiametrofuste" + diametroFuste);
        }
    }

}
```

**I can not work, I am beginner and do not understand where ta wrong, I think the variable that I created in another activity is not being recognized this**

Comment: if u have any question than come to chat box and than ask there too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

If `diametroFuste`  is a double,

```
double  diametroFuste = getIntent().getExtras().get("resultadoDiametrofuste");
tvResultadofuste.setText(""+diametroFuste);
```

**Update:**

In your `TubulaoResultados` Activity

```
final TextView tvResultadofuste = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.<textview's id mentioned in tubulaoresultados.xml file>);
Intent ITubulaoDados = getIntent();

if (ITubulaoDados != null) {
double  diametroFuste = ITubulaoDados.getExtras().get("resultadoDiametrofuste");
tvResultadofuste.setText(Double.toString(diametroFuste));
Log.i("TubulaoResultados","resultadoDiametrofuste" + diametroFuste);
}
```

Comment: diametroFuste is a double, is result of a calculation

Comment: Also you can use this, tvResultadofuste.setText(Double.toString(diametroFuste));

Comment: I think I'm missing somewhere, someone could give an example of how to create a method that will do the calculation x = a + will be the value of x to another activity and how to call the value of x in the other activity in a TextView, thank much, thank you

Comment: modified the question, look back and help me, please

Comment: is with the following error in "double  diametroFuste = ITubulaoDados.getExtras().get("resultadoDiametrofuste");": Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to double

Comment: Just replace this code line, double  diametroFuste = ITubulaoDados.getExtras().getDouble("resultadoDiametrofuste");

Answer (score 0):

String strValue = getIntent.getExtras().getString("resultadoDiametrofuste");

Comment: I think I'm missing somewhere, someone could give an example of how to create a method that will do the calculation x = a + will be the value of x to another activity and how to call the value of x in the other activity in a TextView, thank much, thank you

Comment: modified the question, look back and help me, please

Answer (score 0):

Just try this it works

```
 double diametroFuste;
 Bundle extra=getIntent().getExtras();
 if(extra!=null){
    diametroFuste=extra.getDouble("resultadoDiametrofuste");
 }
```